# Can there be a notification for bounties started on questions you've asked or answered?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications, global-inbox

Can there be a notification for those people that participated in the question in the past (either who asked or answered it) once a bounty is started on it?

Comment: +1 This would be very useful, especially if you have already spent some time on an answer; this can help you to improve it without having to stumble upon the bounty.

Comment: I assumed this was already in place, I can't imagine what the downside of this could be.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan no downside, just something they never thought about like many other things.

Comment: Like you would have gotten right now? :)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος It _seems_ like it...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I mean, the bounties that are set here in order to try such a bounty feature.

Comment: ...[or followed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364420/348196).

Comment: @LittlePickle: See also: [After ten years why are we still not telling folks that their questions have been bountied by good samaritans?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362239/after-ten-years-why-are-we-still-not-telling-folks-that-their-questions-have-bee)

Answer (score 10):

This would be a good feature to apply.

I mean when a question is featured, it's supposed to be featured and stand out from the rest to attract more attention. So sending *one* notification to all answerers and even the OP (if the OP is not the user who placed the bounty) to allow them all to have a chance to improve their respective posts for whatever reason which is needed (new updates, newly seen obstacles, etc.).

Hopefully this feature doesn't require a lot out of SE especially with the more developed sites with questions that have tons of answers (for example, Stack Overflow or Programming Puzzles and Code Golf).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, please make this. I just started a bounty on someone else's question and felt sort of silly commenting just to let the OP know.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it was a good idea 8 years ago (when the question was posed), 2 years ago (when the question was last answered) and still seems like a good idea today. I wonder if this hasn't happened because it's just low on the priorities or if it's logistically more difficult than I'd expect.

Comment: I realize my answer doesn't contribute a lot of new content but I thought this question deserved a bump.

Comment: Another user [got serious about bumping this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362239/879265) 8 hours ago and it already has a score of 12.

Answer (score 2):

As all other answerers mentioned, this was a must feature when the notification system or the bounty system (whichever came earlier) was implemented.

According to one of the Moderator's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362256/298224), it would overwhelm some people with notifications. But from the vote count of the answer, it is clear that most of the user wants this feature.

If it was implemented at the beginning, folks were adopted it. If it is implemented today, it would be very informative for some people.

And,

For other folks who might become 'overwhelmed', **there could be a button in the profile settings to turn on/off the notification for this purpose.**

Comment: Nice affirmation of the prevailing thought, perfect timing too.