# There isn't any notification when a followed post is locked

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, locked-questions, historical-lock, follow-post

I was following a question that was subsequently locked with a historical lock. I haven't received a notification about that event.

For someone that uses the "following" feature for moderating purposes, knowing that a post has been locked is a significant event. It is a signal that the post has been handled in some way.

Please add notifications for post locks/unlocks.

Comment: I agree. For reference see: [Historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) to those (like me) who'd never heard of it.

Comment: This suggestion makes sense. I've added this to our list to look into more and we'll update here when we revisit it.

Comment: @tanj92 Wondering if you would post the reason why this is being declined (i.e. why the team changed their mind on implementing this). Having a planned request be declined can be disheartening, and even more so if no reason is given for that

Comment: @Sonic They may not have an answer. This was apparently cancelled all the way back in Oct of 2020 and just nobody ever updated the post to say it was now declined. You'd likely only get a proper answer from the CM team. The change today was just... housekeeping.

Comment: @JonChan do you have any idea why this request was declined after already being planned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After discussing with a CM internally, I've updated the status to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). I'd like to do some discovery around inbox notifications today and learn more about the different types of notifications we send that impacts users, curators, moderators, etc. I'm a new Product Manager at Stack and would like to think through this holistically as this has merit for moderators that you highlighted in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Please consider checking [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68881/348196) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364420/348196) (inbox notifications for bounties) while you're at it.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Got it, I'll add this to my list. I'm going to spend a lot of time doing an audit of the current inbox notifications in order to get myself more familiarized with the systems we have today.

Comment: I have just realized that if post is deleted, there is also no notification. That one is way more important. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358382/notification-when-a-followed-post-is-deleted

Comment: Thanks @ResistanceIsFutile. I will add this to my list.