# Please notify users who are following a question when a bounty starts or ends

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications, global-inbox, follow-post

When a followed question is edited or closed, it triggers an inbox notification for those who follow it. However, I just noticed that starting a bounty does not trigger an inbox notification, nor does ending it.

I believe that a bounty is as important as an edit and most, if not all users would want to know when a bounty is started on a question that they follow.

I'd argue that it's also important to get notified when the bounty *ends*. This is because a user might follow a bountied question because they would like to start a new bounty if the current one ends without a satisfying outcome.

**Can bounties be added to the list of actions that trigger a notification?**

Comment: I agree with this idea. However, it's not completely clear to me if you're suggesting this be *only* when following a question, or should it also apply to any followed answer to a question when the bounty is posted. Personally, I think having it be just for a followed question makes the most sense since a bounty would usually not directly affect any answer I'm following.

Comment: @John Agreed, that's exactly my idea. A bounty is a question-related action, so following an answer should not be affected. Just like when a question is closed (or edited), it doesn't trigger a notification for anyone who's only following one (or more) of its answers but not following the question itself.

Comment: Authors aren't currently notified of bounties being started on their questions.

Comment: @Sonic I wasn't aware of this. Well, that's probably another potential feature request. I think they _should_ be notified. That said, I believe it's even more important with followed posts because most bounties (with the exception of meta) are started by authors anyway.

Comment: I would be alright with this change, provided, I could disable the feature.  I also would require the ability to submit a close vote, in those rare cases, where a user knows just enough and starts a bounty to prevent a question from being closed.

Comment: The relevant feature request: [Can there be a notification for bounties started on questions you've asked or answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68881/335251)